# IF.. INSERT.. ELSE UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, insert, sql-insert

Someone can help me?
I have 3 table on my database

1. admin_ (id_admin, name, password)
2. user_ (id_user, id_admin, name, phone_number)
3. rank (id_rank, id_admin, total_user)

admin_

| id_admin | username |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | QG_ |
| 2 | me |

user_

| id_user | id_admin | name | phone_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | wirno | +628877812532 |
| 2 | 1 | arya | +628873812535 |

rank

| id_rank | id_admin | total_user |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |

i want to insert tb_rank from total user added by admin and update when admin added more user and make it with trigger sql

this the query i've try

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM rank WHERE rank.id_admin = id_admin)
THEN
INSERT INTO rank (id_admin, total_user)
SELECT user_.id_admin, COUNT(user_.username) AS total_user FROM user_ GROUP BY user_.id_admin;

ELSE
UPDATE rank, (SELECT user_.id_admin, COUNT(user_.nama_lengkap) AS total_user FROM user_ GROUP BY user_.id_admin) AS total_ad
SET rank.total_user = total_ad.total_user
WHERE rank.id_admin = total_ad.id_admin;

END IF
```

Comment: 'i want to create table rank' - rank is a reserved word in 8.0 don't use it and anyway your table definition is for tb_rank.. Also add your create statement and the rest of the trigger

Comment: Provide complete DDL for the tables.